# Cleaning ages in Talend Tmap

Tags: talend, tmap

I have an age column that has invalid ages and null values, I wish to create a tmap expression to have the mean of all the valid ages from 1 to 120 and then replace the null, invalid (for e.g. 1029), and negative ages with this mean. Could someone help with what kind of functions are available in tmap for this or if someone has implemented the same?

I have tried to check for the expressions already used however couldn't find much. I'm pretty new to Talend and would appreciate some quick guidance. Thanks!

Comment: And “the mean of all valid ages” is derived how? From that data set?

Comment: Yes, I was considering taking the mean of all the valid ages present in the dataset i.e( 1-120)

Answer (score 0):

You won't just be able to do that using a single `tMap`.  That component transforms data from one structure to another with rules/logic along the way.

This requires some additional thinking and ultimately, work.

First, you need to get the average/mean and then apply it to the data set after the fact.

This flow is an example approach of how to do that.

[image: Flow]

**Step 1**, I created a sample data set of people with ages.  There are valid and invalid records (see final `tLogRow` output which shows the before and after)

**Step 2**, I run the data through a `tMap` (after first showing what the `Before` data set looks like) and flag the records for their validity based on the rule you provided.

[image: Step 2]

**Step 3**, I stored the enhanced data set in a `tHashOutput` so it can be referred to later as I will need to apply the average age at a later stage.

**Step 4**, I remove the invalid records (`tFilterRow` component) so I have a clean data set to calculate the average from.

[image: Step 4]

**Step 5**, I use a `tAggregateRow` to calculate the average based on all included records.

[image: Step 5]

**Step 6**, I use `globalMap.put()` to store the average value in memory.  I can then recall that value easily later.  Notice how I convert the integer to a double because an average age may not be a round figure.  You can change that later to suit your needs.

This is the code line ... `globalMap.put("average_age", Double.valueOf(input_row.Age));`

[image: Step 6]

**Step 7**, I recall the stored data set using a `tHashInput` (**Enhanced Data Set** step) and then using a `tMap` (**Update Average**) I change all of the invalid records to the average value I calculated previously.

This is the code for deriving that ...

```
final_in.IsValid ? final_in.Age : (Double)globalMap.get("average_age")
```

*Take note of the connection names in and out if you want to apply the exact same code in your project.*

[image: Step 7]

**Finally**, this is the output from the entire job.  If you didn't work it out, the average age it calculated was <kbd>57</kbd>.

#### Note: I have left them as doubles which means they will have a decimal place.  I've done this on purpose given I don't know what you want to do with an average age that is not round.  I'll leave that to you.

```
Starting job AverageOfDataSet at 10:17 22/04/2023.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3888
[statistics] connected

.---------+---.
|   Before    |
|=--------+--=|
|Person   |Age|
|=--------+--=|
|Person 1 |86 |
|Person 2 |28 |
|Person 3 |120|
|Person 4 |500|
|Person 5 |39 |
|Person 6 |28 |
|Person 7 |3  |
|Person 8 |2  |
|Person 9 |6  |
|Person 10|null|
|Person 11|24 |
|Person 12|10 |
|Person 13|null|
|Person 14|38 |
|Person 15|60 |
|Person 16|32 |
|Person 17|79 |
|Person 18|119|
|Person 19|250|
|Person 20|47 |
|Person 21|11 |
|Person 22|5  |
|Person 23|null|
|Person 24|73 |
|Person 25|73 |
|Person 26|113|
|Person 27|105|
|Person 28|321|
|Person 29|55 |
|Person 30|null|
|Person 31|119|
|Person 32|79 |
|Person 33|97 |
|Person 34|79 |
|Person 35|42 |
|Person 36|18 |
|Person 37|118|
|Person 38|89 |
|Person 39|44 |
|Person 40|70 |
'---------+---'

.---------+-----.
|     After     |
|=--------+----=|
|Person   |Age  |
|=--------+----=|
|Person 1 |86.0 |
|Person 2 |28.0 |
|Person 3 |120.0|
|Person 4 |57.0 |
|Person 5 |39.0 |
|Person 6 |28.0 |
|Person 7 |3.0  |
|Person 8 |2.0  |
|Person 9 |6.0  |
|Person 10|57.0 |
|Person 11|24.0 |
|Person 12|10.0 |
|Person 13|57.0 |
|Person 14|38.0 |
|Person 15|60.0 |
|Person 16|32.0 |
|Person 17|79.0 |
|Person 18|119.0|
|Person 19|57.0 |
|Person 20|47.0 |
|Person 21|11.0 |
|Person 22|5.0  |
|Person 23|57.0 |
|Person 24|73.0 |
|Person 25|73.0 |
|Person 26|113.0|
|Person 27|105.0|
|Person 28|57.0 |
|Person 29|55.0 |
|Person 30|57.0 |
|Person 31|119.0|
|Person 32|79.0 |
|Person 33|97.0 |
|Person 34|79.0 |
|Person 35|42.0 |
|Person 36|18.0 |
|Person 37|118.0|
|Person 38|89.0 |
|Person 39|44.0 |
|Person 40|70.0 |
'---------+-----'

[statistics] disconnected

Job AverageOfDataSet ended at 10:17 22/04/2023. [Exit code  = 0]
```